# Is is possible to record audio (from microphone) in Appcelerator Titanium?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, microphone

I'd like to be able to record audio in app I'm specing out. I'm considering using Titanium and was wondering if it provides access to the Microphone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ti.Media.createAudioRecorder()

http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/latest/Titanium.Media.AudioRecorder-object

Answer (score 0):

An updated audio recorder module has been released and works with Titanium SDK 2.1+

Find out more info http://vocalrank.com/audiorecorder. There's also a sample apk which you can download and play with which demonstrates some of the available methods.

Comment: Sounds promising but no online sample and no contact info. Seems like a no brainer to offer a web demo of a web-based product.

Comment: Clay, re-read what I posted. 

There is a sample apk which is available for download. It has been available from the day of release. Go to the website, find the image that says 'download free audio recorder app', and then click it to begin the download. It's better to do this from your mobile device since installation will be faster. Email me for support.